# KsProperty () returns"The data area passed to a system call is too small" ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER while setting camera Zoom value

Tags: directshow

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
KSPROPERTY ksprop;    
ZeroMemory(&ksprop, sizeof(ksprop));
PVOID pData = NULL;
ULONG valueSize = 0;
ULONG dataLength = 0;
KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S cameraControl;
ZeroMemory(&cameraControl, sizeof(cameraControl));
ksprop.Set = PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL;
ksprop.Id = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_ZOOM;
ksprop.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET;
cameraControl.Property = ksprop;
cameraControl.Flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;
cameraControl.Capabilities = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;
cameraControl.Value = 50;

pData = &cameraControl;
dataLength = sizeof(cameraControl);
hr = m_pKsControl->KsProperty(
            &ksprop, sizeof(ksprop),
            pData, dataLength, &valueSize);
```

here hr "The data area passed to a system call is too small. "
I am compiling on vs 2010 on windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to provide a buffer which is too small in fourth parameter.

It's easy to check this out, see [`IKsControl::KsProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs:

> To determine the buffer size that is required for a specific property
>   request, you can call this method with PropertyData set to NULL and
>   DataLength equal to zero. The method returns
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA), and BytesReturned contains the
>   size of the required buffer.

Comment: I tried that i set 3rd,4th parameter NULL but BytesReturned  value is too high(garbage).I guess ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER and ERROR_MORE_DATA are different.Do you have any sample or link for what you saying.

Answer (score 0):

In this KsProperty use case, you should pass KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S structure variable to make this work.

For example

```
KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S kspIn = { 0 };
KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S kspOut = { 0 };
ULONG valueSize = 0;
kspIn.Property.Set    = PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL;
kspIn.Property.Id     = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_ZOOM;
kspIn.Property.Flags  = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET;
kspOut.Property.Set   = PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL;
kspOut.Property.Id    = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_ZOOM;
kspOut.Property.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET;
kspOut.Flags          = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;
kspOut.Capabilities   = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;
kspOut.Value          = 50;

hr = m_pKsControl->KsProperty(
        (PKSPROPERTY)&kspIn, sizeof(kspIn),
        &kspOut, sizeof(kspOut), &valueSize);
```

Should work